# Magento 2 Error “URL key for specified store already exists

Tags: magento2, category, category-tree

Basically i am adding a custom category the problem is when i add two child category with same ***NAME*** in to one ***parent*** category where child category is already present then this shows error of URL KEY.

My code is

```
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath())
            ->setParentId($parentId)
            ->setName('test1')
            ->setIsActive(true);
        $category->save();
```

Is it possible to add two categories with same NAME in one parent category? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add Same category name but please make sure URL key should be different or else Magento will not allow you to add same category name.

Comment: how can i change that URL?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue in more than 3-4 projects.

If you want to resolve this issue, you can upgrade your version with latest one or try below code logic:

Try this solution by overriding below function in your custom module :)

Path: vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Model/Storage

```
protected function doReplace(array $urls){ 
    $this->deleteOldUrls($urls); 
    $data = [];
    $storeId_requestPaths = [];
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $storeId = $url->getStoreId();
        $requestPath = $url->getRequestPath();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM url_rewrite where store_id = $storeId and request_path = '$requestPath'";
        $exists = $this->connection->fetchOne($sql); 
        if ($exists) continue;
        $storeId_requestPaths[] = $storeId . '-' . $requestPath;
        $data[] = $url->toArray();
    }

    // Remove duplication data;
    $n = count($storeId_requestPaths);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++) {
            if ($storeId_requestPaths[$i] == $storeId_requestPaths[$j]) {
                unset($data[$j]);
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        $this->insertMultiple($data);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {
        /** @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite[] $urlConflicted */
        $urlConflicted = [];
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $urlFound = $this->doFindOneByData(
                [
                    UrlRewriteData::REQUEST_PATH => $url->getRequestPath(),
                    UrlRewriteData::STORE_ID => $url->getStoreId(),
                ]
            );
            if (isset($urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID])) {
                $urlConflicted[$urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID]] = $url->toArray();
            }
        }
        if ($urlConflicted) {
            throw new \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Exception\UrlAlreadyExistsException(
                __('URL key for specified store already exists.'),
                $e,
                $e->getCode(),
                $urlConflicted
            );
        } else {
            throw $e->getPrevious() ?: $e;
        }
    }

    return $urls;
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Thanks,

Ketan T.